# Simple injector to register open generics with multiple constructors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

Hi I'm trying to implement this extension method I've found in [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=88) for simple injector since it doesn't support registration for an specific constructor out of the box.

according to the article I need to register the service with a fake delegate but since I'm using an open generic I can't do that.

so far this is the code that I've done:

```
 public sealed class ConstructorSelector : IConstructorSelector
    {
        public static readonly IConstructorSelector MostParameters =
            new ConstructorSelector(type => type.GetConstructors()
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length).First());

        public static readonly IConstructorSelector LeastParameters =
            new ConstructorSelector(type => type.GetConstructors()
                .OrderBy(c => c.GetParameters().Length).First());

        private readonly Func<Type, ConstructorInfo> _selector;

        public ConstructorSelector(Func<Type, ConstructorInfo> selector)
        {
            _selector = selector;
        }

        public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type type)
        {
            return _selector(type);
        }
    }

    public interface IConstructorSelector
    {
        ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type type);
    }

    public static class SimpleInjectorExtesions
    {
        public static void RegisterOpenGeneric(this Container container,
            Type serviceType, 
            Type implementationtype, IConstructorSelector selector)
        {   
            //TODO: register the service with a fake delegate   
            container.ExpressionBuilt += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.RegisteredServiceType != serviceType) return;
                var ctor = selector.GetConstructor(implementationtype);

                var parameters =
                    from p in ctor.GetParameters()
                    select container.GetRegistration(p.ParameterType, true)
                                    .BuildExpression();

                e.Expression = Expression.New(ctor, parameters);
            };
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You would have more luck overriding the `Container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since it doesn't support registration for an specific constructor out
>   of the box

Simple Injector doesn't support this for a good reason. You should prefer letting your components have a single public constructor. Having [multiple constructors is considered to be an anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

If for some reason you can't follow this advice, here are some alternatives.

A simple solution would be to create a new type inside your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) that inherits from the open generic type and defines just one single constructor. You can register that type instead:

```cs
// new sub type
private sealed class SingleCtorOpenType<T> : OpenType<T>
{
    public SingleCtorOpenType(IDep1 dep1, IDep2 dep2) 
        : base(dep1, dep2) { }
}

// registration
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IOpenType<>), 
    typeof(SingleCtorOpenType<>));
```

This is the most pragmatic solution if you're dealing with just one type. If you have many types that have multiple constructors, overriding the container's [constructor resolution behavior](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-constructor-resolution-behavior) would be better. You can write a custom `IConstructorResolutionBehavior` implementation for your open generic type:

```cs
public class SpecialConstructorResolutionBehavior
    : IConstructorResolutionBehavior
{
    private IConstructorResolutionBehavior original;

    public SpecialConstructorResolutionBehavior(
        IConstructorResolutionBehavior original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type serviceType, 
        Type implementationType)
    {
        if (serviceType.IsGenericType &&
            serviceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IOpenType<>))
        {
            // do alternative constructor selection here for open types.
            // For instance:
            return (
                from ctor in implementationType.GetConstructors()
                orderby ctor.GetParameters().Length descending
                select ctor)
               .First();
        }

        // fall back to default behavior
        return original.GetConstructor(serviceType, implementationType);
    }
}
```

You can register this as follows:

```cs
container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior =
    new SpecialConstructorResolutionBehavior(
        container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior);
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to supply an `Expression` to the extension method to force the selection of a specific constructor, you can create an extension method that excepts an `Expression<Func<object>>` extracts the `NewExpression` for you like this:

```cs
public static void RegisterOpenGeneric(this Container container, 
    Type openGenericServiceType,
    Type openGenericImplementation, 
    Expression<Func<object>> constructorSelector)
{
    var constructor = 
        ((NewExpression)constructorSelector.Body).Constructor;
}
```

You can call this extension method as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IList<>), typeof(List<>),
    constructorSelector: () => new List<int>());
```

But now the trouble starts. The constructor passed in is from `List<int>`, but we should be able to get any `List<T>`, so you will have to convert that `List<int>.ctor()` to the constructor of the type you are resolving. As far as I know, .NET lacks convenient helper methods such as `ConstructorInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()` and `ConstructorInfo.MakeGenericMethod()` overloads, so you'll need to do some querying and fiddling to find the correct constructor.

It will probably be easiest if you integrate this model with the `IConstructorResolutionBehavior` extendability mechanism, since the `RegisterOpenGeneric` methods calls that interface.

So your solution could look like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Advanced;
using SimpleInjector.Extensions;

public static class OpenGenericConstructorExtensions
{
    public static void EnableOpenGenericConstructorSelection(
        this ContainerOptions options)
    {
        var selectors = new List<Func<Type, ConstructorInfo>>();

        options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior = 
            new ConstructorResolutionBehavior(
                options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior, selectors);

        options.Container.SetItem("selectors", selectors);
    }

    public static void RegisterOpenGeneric(this Container container, 
        Type openGenericServiceType,
        Type openGenericImplementation, 
        Expression<Func<object>> constructorSelector)
    {
        var selectors = (List<Func<Type, ConstructorInfo>>)
            container.GetItem("selectors");

        if (selectors == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "call Options.EnableOpenGenericConstructorSelection first.");

        var constructor = 
            ((NewExpression)constructorSelector.Body).Constructor;

        selectors.Add(type =>
        {
            if (type == openGenericImplementation || (type.IsGenericType && 
                type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericImplementation))
            {
                return GetConstructorForType(type, constructor);
            }

            return null;
        });

        container.RegisterOpenGeneric(openGenericServiceType, 
            openGenericImplementation);
    }

    private static ConstructorInfo GetConstructorForType(
        Type closedImplementationType, 
        ConstructorInfo closedConstructor)
    {
        var parameters = closedConstructor.GetParameters();

        var constructors =
            from ctor in closedImplementationType.GetConstructors()
            where ctor.GetParameters().Length == parameters.Length
            let parameterPairs = ctor.GetParameters().Zip(parameters, (p1, p2) =>
                new { left = p1.ParameterType, right = p2.ParameterType })
            where parameterPairs.All(pair => pair.left == pair.right ||
                    (pair.left.IsGenericType && pair.right.IsGenericType &&
                    pair.left.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == pair.right.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            select ctor;

        return constructors.Single();
    }

    private sealed class ConstructorResolutionBehavior 
        : IConstructorResolutionBehavior
    {
        private readonly IConstructorResolutionBehavior original;
        private readonly List<Func<Type, ConstructorInfo>> constructorSelectors;

        public ConstructorResolutionBehavior(
            IConstructorResolutionBehavior original,
            List<Func<Type, ConstructorInfo>> constructorSelectors)
        {
            this.original = original;
            this.constructorSelectors = constructorSelectors;
        }

        public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type serviceType, 
            Type implementationType)
        {
            var constructors =
                from selector in this.constructorSelectors
                let constructor = selector(implementationType)
                where constructor != null
                select constructor;

            return constructors.FirstOrDefault() ?? 
                this.original.GetConstructor(serviceType, 
                    implementationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Since a custom `IConstructorResolutionBehavior` implementation is needed, you will always have to call the `EnableOpenGenericConstructorSelection` which is defined in the example above. This is how the code can be used:
    var container = new Container();

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.Options.EnableOpenGenericConstructorSelection();

container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IList<>), typeof(List<>), 
    constructorSelector: () => new List<int>());

var list = container.GetInstance<IList<string>>();
var listOfObject = container.GetInstance<IList<object>>();
```

Comment: I can't avoid the situation to ask again how it could be the case to implement it as an extension method and use an expression to select the a specific constructor something like  _container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(serviceType),typeof(ImplementationType), x=> new implementation(constructor);